# Get child of the element in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
<div
    class="btnWrap"
    data-testid="footer-button"
>
    <button
    class="Polaris-Button Polaris-Button--primary"
    type="button"
    >
    <span
        class="Polaris-Button__Content"
    >
        <span
        class="Polaris-Button__Text"
        >
        Button
        </span>
    </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have this component and to test it I have done

```
 test("Test footer button disable false", () => {
    args.disabled = false;
    const { debug, getByTestId } = render(
      <AppProvider>
        <Footer {...args} />
      </AppProvider>
    );

    const element = getByTestId("footer-button");
    console.log(getByTestId("footer-button").closest("button"));
    expect(element.getAttribute("disabled")).toBe(null);
    debug();
  });
```

I want to check if that button is disabled or not so to get that button I have used

```
        console.log(getByTestId("footer-button").closest("button"));
```

But the output of this is null.
How can I do that?

In my main code I can not give testid to the button component.

Comment: How about [getByRole](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole) instead of using `.closest`? This way you can test through accessibility. E.g. `expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /button/i })).toBeDisabled()`. As a side note: `.toBeDisabled()` comes from [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom)